# Ajax Call - Data not being loaded in to my Database

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I am having an issue posting data to my database from an external API call.  When I call the API - on the client side it returns all the results.  With the response object - I want to loop through all the results and push them to my database.  For some reason - when I start looping through the results my server side route is only pushing the first 10 or so records in and then nothing else.   Anyone know what might be happening?    Here is what my client side Javascript looks like.

```js
function coinMarketCapAPICall(){
 var queryUrl = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0";
 $.ajax({
  url: queryUrl,
  method: "GET"
 }).done(function(response){
  console.log(response);

  // Looping through all the data from our API call. And creating a new object for each
  // cryptocurrency.
  for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){



   var newCryptoRow = {
    currency_id: response[i].id,
    name: response[i].name,
    symbol: response[i].symbol,
    rank: response[i].rank,
    price_usd: response[i].price_usd,
    price_btc: response[i].price_btc,
    twentyfour_volume_usd: response[i]['24h_volume_usd'],
    market_cap_usd: response[i].market_cap_usd,
    available_supply: response[i].available_supply,
    total_supply: response[i].total_supply,
    max_supply: response[i].max_supply,
    percent_change_1h: response[i].percent_change_1h,
    percent_change_24h: response[i].percent_change_24h,
    percent_change_7d: response[i].percent_change_7d,
    last_updated: response[i].last_updated
   }

   $.ajax("/api/cryptodata",{
    type: "POST",
    data: newCryptoRow
   });
  }
 })
}
```

Then on the server side - I have a route that is intended to take the results and push them back in to my database looks like this.

```js
 app.post("/api/cryptodata", function(req, res){
  connection.query('INSERT INTO pricings SET ?', req.body,
   function(error, result, fields){
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log("this is the Coinmarket call", result.body);
   })
  })
```

Again - Not sure what is going on here - appreciate any help!

Comment: You're making a *new* request for every row, resulting in a *ton* of requests at once. Change your backend to accept more than one at once.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how that could look?

Comment: I don't know databases, but it would be trivial to parse the post as an array, and then make a query for each item. (might well be a better way to make only a single query though)